# Programming calculator with no buttons (entering entire expression)

Tags: python

In my code the user enters an expression (`userExp`) where then the code splits it into a string under `expression_list`. I want to join the `expression_list` when printing the result so output shows up like this: `2 + 2 = 4`, but when I try to I get this result:

```
    print (''.join(expression_list.split(',')[::1]), '=', answer)  
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How would I change it from `['3', '-', '4'] = -1` to `3 - 4 = -1`?

```
import operator

operList = ["+", "/", "%", "//", "**", "-",""," "]
Error1 = "Something is wrong with your equation: there is nothing in it."
Error2 = "Something is wrong with your equation: it does not feel complete."


def printGreeting():
    print("Hello, welcome to Equation Calculator")
    print("Enter in the expression that you want evaluated and the program will do the rest.")

def getExpression():
    userExp = input("Enter mathematical expression here: ")
    expression_list = userExp.split()
    print(expression_list)
    if not userExp.isdigit() or userExp.isalpha():
        print(Error2)
    if operList[6] or operList[7] in userExp:
        print(Error1)
    return expression_list

def add(expression_list):
    answer = int(expression_list[0]) + int(expression_list[2])
    return answer

def sub(expression_list):
    answer = int(expression_list[0]) - int(expression_list[2])
    return answer

def exp(expression_list):
    answer = int(expression_list[0]) ** int(expression_list[2])
    return answer

def div(expression_list):
    answer = int(expression_list[0]) / int(expression_list[2])
    return answer

def fdiv(expression_list):
    answer = int(expression_list[0]) // int(expression_list[2])
    return answer

def modu(expression_list):
    answer = int(expression_list[0]) % int(expression_list[2])
    return answer


printGreeting()
expression_list = getExpression() 
if operList[0] in expression_list:
    answer = add(expression_list)
    print (answer)

elif operList[5] in expression_list:
    answer = sub(expression_list)
    print (''.join(expression_list.split(',')[::1]), '=', answer)

elif operList[4] in expression_list:
    answer = exp(expression_list)
    print (answer)

elif operList[1] in expression_list:
    answer = div(expression_list)
    print (answer)

elif operList[3] in expression_list:
    answer = fdiv(expression_list)
    print (answer)

elif operList[2] in expression_list:
    answer = modu(expression_list)
    print (answer)
```

Comment: Could you just `eval(userExp)`?  Or is this cheating?

Comment: Are you going to support the [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)? Are you going to support [brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket_(mathematics))?

Comment: It's more complicated than it seems, for example, you'll need to take into account precedence and brackets. I'd take a look at [`pyparsing`](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/). Or, if you want to implement the whole thing yourself for educational purposes, consider [shunting yard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). Finally, Python [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the expression is entered with spaces between numbers and operator and it is a simple calculation using only two values you could try the following where the expression entered is split into a list and passed into the add function (if it contains an + symbol) and then the add function adds the two values returning the answer back to where the function was called from.

```
import operator

operList = ["+", "/", "%", "//", "**", "-",""," "]
Error1 = "Something is wrong with your equation: there is nothing in it."
Error2 = "Something is wrong with your equation: it does not feel complete."


def printGreeting():
    print("Hello, welcome to Equation Calculator")
    print("Enter in the expression that you want evaluated and the program will do the rest.")

def getExpression():
    userExp = input("Enter mathematical expression here: ")
    expression_list = userExp.split()
    print(expression_list)
    if not userExp.isdigit() or userExp.isalpha():
        print(Error2)
    if operList[6] or operList[7] in userExp:
        print(Error1)

    if operList[0] in expression_list:
        answer = add(expression_list)
        print (answer)

    #carry on ifs for calc.


def add(expression_list):
    answer = int(expression_list[0]) + int(expression_list[2])
    return answer

#add functions for each calc like above


printGreeting()
userExp = getExpression()
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem that is causing the error is that expression_list is already a list not a string so calling split on it is meaningless.

However, if you remove that issue you are then trying to join a list a two strings. You should either join the list and then join the resultant string with the others or add them to the list. Something like:

```
''.join(expression_list+['=', answer])
```

Other people are dealing with whether you are going about the task in a sensible way - this is purely answering the specific problem you have encountered.